# Why does my multiplayer javascript game slow down when another client (new tab) connects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a simple multiplayer game using canvas, socket.io and node.js.
Everything's OK until another person connects (I open another tab and load the game there). When that happens, everything slows down and eventually stops (I can' move around).

How it works:
When someone connects to the server, the server saves his socket in an array object and starts communication with the client. The client sends an object containing it's name and position and then the server goes trough that array of sockets and sends that to everyone else who is connected. When a client receives a message, it extracts the data, does something with it (like drawing based on the position) and then sets a timeout in 10ms to reply to the server with his position and name. This goes on and on and works well until I open a new window/tab and reconnect, as I said.

Why does it slow down when I start another client? Here's the code:

server.js (this is just a piece of code, the rest is from the socket.io example)

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
     socket.emit('init', {id: names[players.length], level: 5});
     socket.on('got', function (data) { 
          console.log("got");
          players.push(new Player(socket));
          socket.emit('update', {msg: "ks"});
     });

     socket.on('update', function (data){
          for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
          {
               players[i].socket.emit('update', {msg: data});
          }
     });
});

Player = function(socket)
{
     this.socket = socket
}
```

game.js

```
self.socket.on('init', function (data) {
      self.pl = new self.Player(data.id, data.level);
      console.log(self.pl.id);
      self.defined = true;
      self.socket.emit('got', { my: "data" });
 });

 self.socket.on('update', function (data){
      self.pars(data);
          setTimeout(function(){self.socket.emit('update', {'pos': self.pl.pos, 'id': self.pl.id})}, 10);        
 });
```

Comment: Just as an aside, I would use a second client.  I run Firefox and Chrome side-by-side to achieve this.  If the problem continues to manifest then, then I would suggest you have a real problem.

Comment: But I even tried it on separate computers, I don't see how using two separate browsers could solve anything, if that's what you're suggesting! I'll try it though, thanks for the tip.

Comment: if it first just slows down, and then grinds to a halt, then it sounds like a recursion error... trace and see if code is run that shouldn't be run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is resource issues, I'm guessing this is all running on your local machine, you might just be eating up all the resources.

It could be anything from cpu to connections. Hard to say without more info.

Is your code leaving connection to the clients open the entire time time?

Comment: You mean that two pictures and a green background can do that? Well, I hope that's the problem, but as I sad I ran it on separate computers and the issue was still there!

Comment: you're doing network communications every 10ms, sounds pretty stressful. i'm guessing this is 1 computer handling the server (2 connections every 10ms) and one client (1 connection every 10ms). I'd bet if you bump that up to 100ms, you'd see much better performance.

Comment: I should say message rather than connection, as it looks as if the connections would be left open.

Comment: Hey! Turns out you were right! It doesn't lag/pause now! Thanks man, is there some way to like, give you reputation points?

Comment: Theres a check mark right to his answer to indicate that this answer was helpfull and solved your question (only for the main answer, not the comments). But you can upvote the answer, too.